# Configuration - apache2.conf on Debian

Tags: debian

Excuse me! But this is my second day on Debian, and I already have a lot of questions:

I tried to save from the editor php file in / var / www / directory, but I get a message:

```
Unable to save /var/www/file.php
Error: Unable to create tmp file in /var/www
```

Is the problem in apache2.conf file, because of the options in it I can not change evan when I'm a root?

How should be look configuration files for apache, php and mysql to work as normal in WAMP on Win?

Comment: You don't have permission to save the file to `/var/www` I assume. You need to be root to write files to that directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be root to write to /var/www, or you need to be the user (or group, depending on the ownership of the directory).

You can start with the `whoami` command:

```
[username@host username]$ whoami
username
```

This tells you that you are logged in as `username`

Now, you can do `ls -al /var/www` and get:

```
[username@host username]$ ls -al /var/www
total 12
drwxr-xr-x    3 root     root         4096 May 12  2004 .
drwxr-xr-x   21 root     root         4096 Mar 31  2004 ..
drwxr-xr-x    3 root     root         4096 Mar 30  2004 manual
```

The `drwxr-xr-x` are the permissions, in this case rwx (read/write/exec) for owner, rx (read/execute, NOT write) for group, and rx for everyone else.

The first root is the owner, the second root is the group.

If the directory was `drwxrwxr-x` the user and group are rwx and everyone else is rx only.

So, if the permission was:

```
drwxrwxr-x    3 root     webdev         4096 May 12  2004 .
```

Both the user (root) and group (webdev) have rwx permissions (read/write/execute) and you could write a file if you were either the user root, in the group webdev, or both.

Read a little on file permissions and such with a tutorial like:
http://www.grymoire.com/unix/Permissions.html